# Blendshape + animation, result in error

Tags: unity, error

I'm trying to use a blendshape in **Unity**, it's a blendshape that shrinks the model:

[image][image]

But when I run an animation and use the blendshape this happens:

[image]
[image]

**Anyone know what might be happening? Any thought can be helpful.**

Comment: Why don't you shrink the armature?

Comment: Can that be done? I'm sorry, I'm noob. I suspected that the problem was that Unity did not resized any bone. How can I also shrink the armature?

Comment: Scale is also an animatable parameter. Just scale down the bones and hit "i" to make keyframes for them. Be sure to choose LocRotScale for keying set.

Comment: I have tried but I have not succeeded. Sorry, I need a more detailed explanation.

But I confirmed that the problem is that the bones are not scaled when the blendshapes are modified and that causes the error. I just need to know how to apply blendshape also to the armature.