# Blendshape the armature

Tags: armature

I’m doing a blendshape that shrinks a character and I need to shrink the armature too.

Is it possible to do this in blender? How is it done?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor on the center (Shift C), use the cursor as pivot point. Select the mesh in object mode, turn off the armature modifier, press S to scale around the cursor, move your mouse but don't click: in the left bottom corner you will read the amount of scaling according to the mouse movements, read the value when you're satisfied (let's say it's 0.563), press .563 and Enter. Then select the armature, go to edit mode, activate all the armature layers, press A to select all, then press S .563 Enter. Reactivate the armature modifier.

Comment: Thank you! That is very useful, because I didn't know how to scale to a value chosen by me. But this doesn't make the mesh and the armature to be joint during the blendshape, right? I need the armature shrink when the mesh shrinks in the blendshape.

Comment: which is the goal? If the armature is affecting the mesh, scaling the armature in pose mode will scale the mesh accordingly; the scaling can drive a shapekey to control the exact shape of the scaled mesh. What do you need that can't be done with this setup?

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. :) I'm trying to solve this problem:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137209/blendshape-animation-result-in-error

That's why I need that during the blendshape shrink of the model, the bones also shrink.

Comment: Don't use a blendshape to shrink the mesh.  Use the armature to shrink the mesh.  Then you don't have to do anything special.